# HTML Input Field Min/Max Length

Tags: html, forms

I need a input field only accept string 6-10 Upper case and lower case

```
<input type"text" pattern>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<input type="text" minlength=2 maxlength=10>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `type="number"`

Answer (score 0):

use `minlength` and `maxlength` to dictate length. For example,

```html
<input minlength="6" maxlength="10" type="text">
```

will only accept input between six and ten characters.